# Hola, tengo una duda, debo de configurar una autenticacion de SAML 2.0 usando otka como identidad de proveedor

Tags: login, webforms, saml, autenticacion

En mi proyecto de Visual Studio agregue el saml.config con los datos necesarios, relacionados a otka, pero no he podido lograr el redireccionamiento necesario para la autenticacion.

Este es mi codigo en el Code Behind del Inicio de Sesion:

```
using ComponentSpace.SAML2;
using ComponentSpace.SAML2.Bindings;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SAML.AYB
{
    public partial class wfrmInicioSesion : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SAMLIdentityProvider.SendSSO(Response, "abcdefg@hotmail.com");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es mi codigo en el saml.config, creo que en el Service provider podria estar el problema, pero no lo he entendido bien aun:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SAMLConfiguration xmlns="urn:componentspace:SAML:2.0:configuration">
    <ServiceProvider
      Name="http://www.okta.com/exk703lsdyYZg3r5n697"
      Description="Okta"
      AssertionConsumerServiceUrl="https://trial-8492730.okta.com/sso/saml2/0oa70ox5f1tbn545z697">
        <LocalCertificates>
            <Certificate FileName="Certificates\okta.cert"/>
        </LocalCertificates>
    </ServiceProvider>

    <PartnerIdentityProviders>
        <PartnerIdentityProvider
        Name="http://www.okta.com/exk703lsdyYZg3r5n697"
        Description="Okta"
        SingleSignOnServiceUrl="https://trial-8492730.okta.com/app/trial-8492730_saybayb_1/exk703lsdyYZg3r5n697/sso/saml"
        SingleLogoutServiceUrl="https://trial-8492730.okta.com/app/trial-8492730_saybayb_1/exk703lsdyYZg3r5n697/slo/saml">
            <PartnerCertificates>
                <Certificate FileName="Certificates\okta.cert"/>
            </PartnerCertificates>
        </PartnerIdentityProvider>
    </PartnerIdentityProviders>
</SAMLConfiguration>
```

Este le metadata que saque de okta:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://www.okta.com/exk703lsdyYZg3r5n697">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIDqjCCApKgAwIBAgIGAYoFsMTOMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEG A1UECAwKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzENMAsGA1UECgwET2t0YTEU MBIGA1UECwwLU1NPUHJvdmlkZXIxFjAUBgNVBAMMDXRyaWFsLTg0OTI3MzAxHDAaBgkqhkiG9w0B CQEWDWluZm9Ab2t0YS5jb20wHhcNMjMwODE3MjI0ODQ1WhcNMzMwODE3MjI0OTQ1WjCBlTELMAkG A1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcMDVNhbiBGcmFuY2lzY28xDTAL BgNVBAoMBE9rdGExFDASBgNVBAsMC1NTT1Byb3ZpZGVyMRYwFAYDVQQDDA10cmlhbC04NDkyNzMw MRwwGgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg1pbmZvQG9rdGEuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIB CgKCAQEAwJp32uHpC4mS7OFguD6Oy1iBbjgqm+I24wOe3MbQnLkct/SRx+mrSdrcy84n6rVkJbmW w5VzokGgFcoBFH5dz+05Blhk5cHVmbpao03VvoGJ6h0fcX/c40jvgFoGod4aIag5G3uRZ5/I1r/U epAQ2Y5TgZgklJlaDFykFPA86k/xZNTqp6F36JQjGTeL3aElAN2msncpvM7cEFLz+xftne66z9WU kULKWdvObMB3+SpP4alV/d3xL7KqiblL7nHnfuJIfKax0p3XGgFDZSj5YI2fPLSr9T1QJBxBH/GW eYMRhcLo9+BhvPAyR25WZeZ2f6nX9JOr1QUS+E3Mo/7fZwIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IB AQAJqx65nyO47qD2I7h0ahlE5JripDzutrTkXRv++WoixKCevXYWYi4s4R9YyJEZUyJElNVs/sEM NVU2YcAuIw2auWyfpde106big4EEvhoQLbm2VRvWT1dbp6nubtJO0R4mX1Fy+bYe0z8Q8SQ64hGK 1SOBoXzb2unhB6iNR4RmZ3jcEqzFy96ssFLFWW/JwnouXMNbpeHiArxRr6eX0pQs5vzctXVJeIN2 vz5R7ahcQlA+mvju9x/Pn0Pwv7WMIksPOfYMBQdis8Hcls45KYG9WknnZSLuyLs8dXmycEIFaKuE ALTacvm4z8NLSFKyG3J4Xn2ocvKtJ95BRB6XbKGO</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://trial-8492730.okta.com/app/trial-8492730_saybayb_1/exk703lsdyYZg3r5n697/sso/saml"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://trial-8492730.okta.com/app/trial-8492730_saybayb_1/exk703lsdyYZg3r5n697/sso/saml"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Y este es el error que se me presenta al iniciar sesion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden ayudar Saludos!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!